# Socket stuck in endless loop while trying to send buffer to multiple clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, share

I am using socket.io to set up multiple clients and then when one client wants to send any file to others present, they can send it. But in my share file function, the code is stuck in endless loop. It doesn't go in the condition given.
My server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const socketio = require("socket.io");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const expressServer = app.listen(3000);
const io = socketio(expressServer)

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
  socket.on('file-meta',function(data){
     io.emit('fs-meta',data.metadata);
  })
  socket.on('fs-start',function(data){
     io.emit('fs-meta',{});
  })
  socket.on('file-raw',function(data){
     io.emit('fs-share',data.buffer);
  })
})
```

my sender.html file

```
<div class="file-input">
 <label for="file-input">Select files for sharing</label>
 <input type="file" id="file-input">
</div>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/downloadjs/1.4.1/download.min.js"></script>
<script>
 const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
 let fileShare = {};
 document.querySelector('#file-input).addEventListener("change",function(e){
 let file = e.target.files[0];
 if(!file){
  return;
 }
 let reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function(e){
  let buffer = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
  shareFile({
   filename:file.name,
   total_buffer_size:buffer.length,
   buffer_size:524288
   },buffer);
 }
 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
})

function shareFile(metadata,buffer){
 socket.emit("file-meta",{metadata:metadata});
 socket.on("fs-share",function(){
   let chunk = buffer.slice(0,metadata.buffer_size);
   buffer = buffer.slice(metadata.buffer_size,buffer.length);
   if(chunk.length !=0){
     socket.emit("file-raw",{buffer:chunk});
   }
 });
}

socket.on("fs-meta",function(metadata){
 fileShare.metadata = metadata;
 fileShare.transmitted = 0;
 fileShare.buffer = [];
 socket.emit("fs-start");
});

socket.on("fs-share",function(buffer){
 fileShare.buffer.push(buffer);
 fileShare.transmitted += buffer.byteLength;
 if(fileShare.transmitted == fileShare.metadata.total_buffer_size){
   download(new Blob(fileShare.buffer),fileShare.metadata.filename);
   fileShare={};
 }else {
   socket.emit("fs-start");
 }
});
</script>
```

I tried checking if the buffer was reaching there or not. If i try to print the buffer log, i can get the uint8array, but after the chunk size goes to zero, instead of stopping it goes to endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

set multiple socket i by adding forEach and store socektid and data as object in server and send according to the socekts ids